# How to subset a pandas dataframe based on iterating through all row values of another df?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have two pandas dataframes: `key_df` and `value_df`

```
key_dict = {"coordinates": ["AB1", "AC1", "AD1", "EF1", ... ], "start": [762, 1274, 1587, 1991, ...], "end": [2481, 1789, 1689, 2211, ...] }

key_df = pd.DataFrame(key_dict)

  coordinates     start       end
0         AB1       762      2481
1         AC1      1274      1789
2         AD1      1587      1689
3         EF1      1991      2211
...       ...      ...       ...

value_dict = {"coordinates": ["AD1", "AB1"], "meta_data": [101, 010]}

value_df = pd.DataFrame(value_dict)

  coordinates  meta_data
0         AD1        101
1         AB1        110
...       ...        ...
```

The `coordinates` column for `key_df` only contains unique values---there are no repeats. Similarly for `value_df`.

I would like to iterate through `value_df` on `coordinates`, checking each value of `coordinates` in `value_df` for the value of `coordinates` in `key_df`. I would then like to return `start` and `end` for these values.

My thought to subset the dataframe and grab the `start` and `end` values would be to create a function:

```
def parse(x, df):   ### 'x' is each row of value_df$coordinates
    df = df[df.coordinates == x]
    return (df.start, df.end)   ## return as a tuple
```

and I would call the function be `parse(x, df=key_df)`

However, I'm not sure how to iterate over `value_df`. `.iterrows()` is quick but it doesn't preserve the row dtype, which may be a problem.

Comment: Does an inner join would be what you are looking for? like `value_df.merge(key_df,on="coordinates",how="inner")`?

Comment: @andrew_reece Nothing. It's a typo on my end. I think all R should be gone now

Comment: @angelwally Yes, but the DataFrames are in fact much larger than above. So I would need to somehow only merge with `start` and `end`

Comment: @angelwally I'm also worried that `merge()` may take up too much RAM, but that could be irrational

Comment: Well, you could try. And as coordinates is unique you can try to put index and use join instead (seems faster: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43003698/2857926)

Comment: @angelwally How does this deal with "non-matching" `coordinates`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just doing a left join will suffice

```
key_df = key_df.merge(value_df,on='coordinates',how='left')
```

Another way could be to reindex value_df on basis of coordinates

```
value_df.index = value_df['coordinates']
common_values = set(key_df.coordinates).intersection(set(value_df.index))

value_df.loc[list(common_values),['start','end']]
```

Comment: Do you have benchmarks which would be faster/more RAM efficient?

Comment: Is it a left join or an inner join?

Comment: What is the difference between `value_df.index = value_df['coordinates']` and using `value.set_index("coordinates", inplace=True)`?

Comment: How does this deal with "non-matching" `coordinates`?

Comment: value_df.index = value_df['coordinates'] and using value.set_index("coordinates", inplace=True) both are same.
non matching coordinates will have start and end as null values.

Answer (score 0):

try following:

```
key_df = pd.DataFrame(key_dict)
key_df.set_index('coordinates', inplace=True)
key_df.loc[value_dict['coordinates']]
```

Comment: How does this deal with "non-matching" `coordinates`?

Comment: Why `value_dict`?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by inner join, and from the result dataframe you can get the start and end, as shown below:

```
result = pd.merge(key_df, value_df, on='coordinates', how='inner')
```