# speeding up agg and join on a billion-record pandas table

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

`[python 3.5.2, pandas 0.24.1, numpy 1.16.1, scipy 1.2.0]`

I have the following pandas dataframes

```
data_pd
    nrows: 1,032,749,584
    cols: ['mem_id':np.uint32, 'offset':np.uint16 , 'ctype':string, 'code':string]

obsmap_pd
    nrows: 10,887,542
    cols: ['mem_id':np.uint32, 'obs_id':np.uint32]    
             (obs_id has consecutive integers between 0 and obsmap_pd nrows)

varmap_pd
    nrows: 4,596
    cols: ['ctype':string, 'code': string, 'var_id':np.uint16]   
             (var_id has consecutive integers between 0 and varmap_pd nrows)
```

These are the steps I am running

```
***
sparse_pd = data_pd.groupby(['mem_id','ctype','code'])['offset'].nunique().reset_index(name='value')
sparse_pd['value'] = sparse_pd['value'].astype(np.uint16)
sparse_pd = pd.merge(pd.merge(sparse_pd, obsmap_pd, on='mem_id', sort=False),
                  varmap_pd, on=['ctype','code'], sort=False)[['obs_id','var_id','value']]
***
```

The purpose of this is to create a scipy csc_matrix in the next step

```
mat_csc = csc_matrix((sparse_pd['value'].values*1., (sparse_pd['obs_id'].values,sparse_pd['var_id'].values)), 
                     shape=(obsmap_pd.shape[0],varmap_pd.shape[0]))
```

The creation of csc_matrix is very fast, but the three lines with the pandas code (between the ***) takes 25.7mins. Any ideas on how this can been speeded up?

Comment: A good strategy is to use join instead of merge and to set_index on your `on` columns. You'll want to set index, join, set indexes join and not all on one line. You can see an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860457/improve-pandas-merge-performance perhaps this is even a duplicate?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Improve Pandas Merge performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860457/improve-pandas-merge-performance)

Comment: Is it all the merge? How long does the groupby step and astype take? You'd be surprised at how slow `.groupby.nunique` can be for a `DataFrame` with possibly tens or hundreds of millions of groups.

Comment: Have you considered using [Dask](https://dask.org/)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to speed up merge is to use join instead:

```
sparse_pd = sparse_pd.\
    .set_index(['mem_id']).join(obsmap_pd.set_index('mem_id']))
    
sparse_pd = sparse_pd.\
    .reset_index().set_index(['ctype','code']).join(varmap_pd.set_index(['ctype','code'])).loc['obs_id','var_id','value']
```

Also, consider using the pipe module in pandas ([documentation here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pipe.html));
you lose some readability but it is probably more optimized.