# Jupyter kernel dies on SageMaker notebook instance when running join operation using pd.merge on large DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I am running a large pandas merge join operation on a `jupyter` notebook running on `SageMaker` notebook instance `ml.t3.large` i.e `8 gb` of memory.

```
import pandas as pd
    
    df1 = pd.DataFrame({ 
                        'ID': [1, 2, 3],
                        'Name': ['A','B','C'],
                        ....
                      })

    df1.shape
    (3000000, 10)
    
    df2 = pd.DataFrame({
                        'ID': [],
                        'Name': [],
                        ....
                      )}
    
    df2.shape
    (50000, 12)
    
                       
    
   
    # Join data
    
    df_merge = pd.merge(
                         df1,
                         df2,
                         left_on = ['ID','Name'],
                         right_on = ['ID','Name'],
                         how = 'left'
                       )
```

When I run this operation, the kernel dies within a minute or so. How can I optimize this operation for memory efficiency?

The `dtypes` are either `int64, object, float64`.

Running `df1.info(memory_usage = "deep")` shows

`dtypes: float64(1), int64(6), object(12) memory usage: 3.1 GB`

Answer (score 1):

For one, combine `ID` and `Name` into one single `id` column, so that Python/Pandas doesn't have to bother with concatenating the two. Then, `index` + `join` is much faster than `merge`, as shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40860457/improve-pandas-merge-performance).

Secondly, if possible, using python native operation tend to be much faster. For example, accessing a key of a python dictionary `a['key1']` is `O(1)`, not `O(n)`.

So if you have 2 dictionaries as this:

```
from random import randint

a = {}
for id in range(3000000):
    a[id] = ['abc' for i in range(10)]

b = {}
for i in range(100000):
    id = randint(1,3000000)
    b[id] = ['def' for j in range(12)]
```

Left-joining like this should be a breeze. It took about 3 secs on my machine (16 GB memory).

```
# Result set
c = {}
null_value = [None for i in range(12)]
for key in a.keys():
    c[key] = a[key] + b.get(key, null_value)
```

Comment: I have 2 pandas DataFrames, are you suggesting `DataFrames` to `dict` to `left-join` and then back to `dfs` ?

Comment: That decision very much depends on your requirement. I'm just giving alternatives. For example, I sometimes see people who always resort to data frames, when all the wanted to do is joining. In that case, pandas would be an overkill. But if the data is already in data frames for one reason or another, try the index and join method. Indexing is similar in concept with a dictionary's key.

Comment: The data is in a DataFrame. I tried the Concat, index and join method and am still running out of memory.

Comment: I just noticed `df1` itself took up 3 GB. Is this expected? If the data is really 3 GB, then the merge result is also at least 3 GB, so you have consumed at least 6 GB total. In that case, maybe better use `df1 = <join operation>` rather than creating a new variable `df_merge = ...`. If this doesn't work, you may need a bigger instance type.